# Minecraft RegistryObject not present

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm a new minecraft modder, and I'm trying to make a new mob bucket item.

Everytime I run the game, the game crashes saying that the RegistryObject for my modded entity isn't present.

Here is the code in question:

```java
public class ItemInit {
    
    private ItemInit() {}
    
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, TheDeepBlue.MODID);
    
    public static final RegistryObject<MobBucketItem> EEL_BUCKET = 
        ITEMS.register("eel_bucket", () -> new MobBucketItem(EntityInit.EEL.get(), Fluids.WATER, SoundEvents.BUCKET_EMPTY_FISH, new Item.Properties().stacksTo(1).tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_MISC)));
    
             
}
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. Please let me know if I need to provide anything else. Thank you.

Comment: Oddly enough, the game works if I replace my modded entity with a vanilla mob

Answer (score 0):

Your entity will load after your item. So EntityInit.EEL is not loaded. You should not use RegistryObject for your entity, but you can directly instantiate it instead.

For example:

```
public static final EntityType<Entity> FOO = EntityType.Builder.of(...)
```

Comment: Did you mean I should load the entity in ItemInit using your code?

Comment: No, your entity will be initialized if you use the code. So you don't need to load it in Iteminit.

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, it would be beneficial to those wishing to assist you if you were to mention the version of Forge that you are targeting. That said, as it appears you are using `DeferredRegistry` and `RegistryObject` to register your entities, etc, I believe that the following information will be correct for your version.

The problem that is occurring, is that the deferred registration is attempting to eagerly construct `MobBucketItem` when it is time to register your bucket item. As Items are registered before Entities, this leads to the `RegistryObject` for `EntityInit.EEL` being empty, hence calling `get()` crashing the mod loading process.

The solution is to use the `MobBucketItem`'s other constructor, which takes a supplier to the entity as its first argument and not an `EntityType`. A `Supplier` is either a class that implements the supplier interface, or a lambda that returns a value of the form `() -> value`. This will look familiar as that is how you provide the value to return to the registry once Forge begins building the Item Registry

```
    public static final RegistryObject<MobBucketItem> EEL_BUCKET = 
        ITEMS.register("eel_bucket", () -> new MobBucketItem(() -> EntityInit.EEL.get(), () -> Fluids.WATER, ()-> SoundEvents.BUCKET_EMPTY_FISH, new Item.Properties().stacksTo(1).tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_MISC)));
```

Internally, Forge deprecates the constructor you were using to make the `MobBucketItem` and wraps the first 3 arguments in suppliers, then calls the form of the constructor which accepts those suppliers. This is specifically to allow the use of modded entities, fluids, and sounds, even if their registries haven't been built yet.

So to wrap up, take the first three arguments you were previously passing into the constructor, and turn them into suppliers. If that version of the constructor does not exist in the version of Forge you are targeting, then I recommend updating your version of Forge to one that does provide that overload.